# Android 11 EventSequenceValidator: IntentStarted during UNKNOWN. exception thrown at start of every activity

Tags: android-activity, android-11

In Android 11 SDK 30 at the start of every activity I get a stack trace as follows:

```
2020-12-30 10:08:00.175 1417-1436/? D/EventSequenceValidator: IntentStarted during UNKNOWN. Intent { cmp=com.lampreynetworks.ahd.health.at.home/.DebugLogActivity }
java.lang.Throwable: EventSequenceValidator#getStackTrace
    at com.google.android.startop.iorap.EventSequenceValidator.logWarningWithStackTrace(EventSequenceValidator.java:260)
    at com.google.android.startop.iorap.EventSequenceValidator.onIntentStarted(EventSequenceValidator.java:106)
    at com.android.server.wm.LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.handleOnIntentStarted(LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.java:139)
    at com.android.server.wm.LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.lambda$veRn_GhgLZLlOHOJ0ZYT6KcfYqo(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$LaunchObserverRegistryImpl$veRn_GhgLZLlOHOJ0ZYT6KcfYqo.accept(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:292)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:201)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

The activities all work and if I didn't look at Logcat I would never have known. However, I do not understand it and it must be sign of some issue that will come back (eventually) to bite me. Anyone understand this behavior and know how to fix it?

I have had this code over many versions from way back at 4.0.3 and have never seen this until now. Note this happens on EVERY activity.

Comment: Well, this is a DEBUG level log, so it may just be for informational purposes.

Comment: @DavidWasser you might very well be right, but in the absence of that knowledge I am concerned I am doing something wrong. Experience tells me when I see unexpected exceptions and stack traces the problem is usually me!

Comment: @BrianReinhold Have you found any solution?

Comment: @DavidWasser I have not. Well, I reverted back to the previous version of Android Studio and am ignoring updates. I have submitted an issue to Google. So far all is quiet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is reporting they will not fix the issue and will remove the code throwing this exception.

See google [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213905918)

Comment: I see they responded to my bug report on this issue - thanks for the notification. I got no email about it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same suspicious log `EventSequenceValidator: IntentStarted during UNKNOWN` from logcat, haven't found a solution yet, but found a reference here, FYI [EventSequenceValidator.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/startop/iorap/src/com/google/android/startop/iorap/EventSequenceValidator.java).

> If any bad transition happened, the state becomse UNKNOWN. The UNKNOWN state
> could be accumulated, because during the UNKNOWN state more IntentStarted may
> be triggered. To recover from UNKNOWN to INIT, all the accumualted IntentStarted
> should termniate.

Comment: I still am getting the error even though there have been several AS updates. I have come to the point of ignoring it. One of these days I will try and see how a bad transition could happen. At the start its only one!

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen in Android 12 ...

Comment: I did not come across this issue recently. From the reference, even if there is a "KNOWN" state, if there is no new intent during that period, the "EventSequenceValidator: IntentStarted during UNKNOWN" log will not be printed.